# how do I long expose in harsh light for a lake view?

Tags: exposure, landscape

I have this problem of long exposure in harsh light. This in a lake side where I wanted to get that silky movement of water with a stone in foreground. However, since the daylight was harsh my images were over exposed and much of the details were lost. How should I get that silky look of water with long exposure in a harsh daylight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either change the aperture to a smaller value, but this might not be enough, so you would need to use a [ND filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_density_filter) which will reduce the intensity of the light, thus allowing you to use a longer shutter speed and still achieve a good picture.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a 10-stop ND filter to cut the amount of light entering the lens.  It works wonders :-)

Comment: Do note that a 10-stop ND filter will very likely give you an essentially black viewfinder. Live View or a similar feature will help if your camera is equipped with it, otherwise you pretty much will need to compose (and possibly focus) first, then put on the ND filter for exposure metering and exposure.